# Scrapy - different page content when download response.body

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to parse page, e.g. `www.page.com/results?sort=price`. I am parsing it with this code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = [
        "www.page.com/results?sort=price",
    ]
    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):

    # some code

    next_page = "www.page.com/results?sort=price&type=12"
    yield response.follow(next_page, self.get_models)

def get_models(self, response):
    f = open('/tmp/test/file1.txt', 'w')
    f.write(response.url)
    f.write(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
    f.close()
```

The output file is different than file generate by this code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = [
        "www.page.com/results?sort=price&type=12",
    ]
    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.get_models)

def get_models(self, response):
    f = open('/tmp/test/file2.txt', 'w')
    f.write(response.url)
    f.write(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
    f.close()
```

When I download page via `scrapy shell 'www.page.com/results?sort=price&type=12'` The output is similar like `file2.txt`. The problem is, that in the file1.txt, there is no tags with data I need to crawl. What is the difference between this two way to crawl page, why is the downloaded file different?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the real URL or the output logs, but is possible that the first link is adding some cookies that change the behaviour of the second link.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the second case you going to the wrong url. Check your logs to make sure. I'm not sure how [response.follow](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow) works. I don't see any reason to use it here because you are using the full URL (not only path). 
Try to change it to simple `Request`

```
def parse(self, response):

    # some code

    next_page = "www.page.com/results?sort=price&type=12"
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, self.get_models)
```